# How to fix gas limit issue when doing official Ethereum Tutorial?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, bitcoin

I'm trying to work on this tutorial for past three hours and I just don't understand why are there so many holes to do it.

> https://ethereum.org/greeter

It took me forever to figure out what it meant by:

var greeterFactory = eth.contract()

At the time of writing, I'm trying to execute the `loadScript('greeter.js')` but I am unable to because it keeps on throwing  `Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

This should not be true because in my Genesis block, I've set the gas limit to 2000000000

So I decided to run `miner.start()` after setting the `eth.coinbase` to the account in concern [the account which `eth.accounts[0]`] **and it's doing nothing but making my Ubuntu machine lag with I/O usage absolute maximum!**

Secondly, I know I'm the test client and not live client because I ran the console as `gth --datadir ./myDir --networkid 30304 console 2>>mylog.log`

It's very frustrating and I'm not new to programming [*relatively*]

Comment: Insufficient funds means you don't have enough Ether in your account to perform the transaction - it's not about gas limits. Also, please modify your question to actually ask some questions - it's a bit unclear what you want to ask.